# Setting Group Type for new Active Directory Entry in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices, distribution-list

I'm trying to set the group type for a new Active Directory Entry via VB.NET and DirectoryServices to create a distribution list.

How do I access the ADS_GROUP_TYPE enumerations?

Specifically I'm after ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, you can't actually get access to the enumerations.

Just a wee nitpick, this constant doesn't need to be an object, you can make it an int32 -

Const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP As Object = &H2

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the com ActiveDS Dll and import the namespace using ActiveDS, then you will get the above enum value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can access the enumerations via .NET so instead I created the specific constant I needed. For what it's worth here's my code:

> ```
>         Const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP As Object = &H2
>         adNewGroup.Properties("groupType").Value = ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP
> ```

Refactoring welcome!